# How to create a Xml Document from a fully escaped Xml string?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

**Question Background:**

I have an XML response from a web service (that I am unable to control the content of) that I would like to validate. For example, often the response will have a URL in it that has query string parameters using a "&".

**Code:**

The following code gives an example of escaping an XML string with illegal characters. This will indeed produce an escaped string:

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
string encodedXml = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xml);

// RESULT: &lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
```

If I know attempt to load this escaped XML into a new Xml Document, I will receive an error that the first character of the XML is not valid:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

// Error will occur here.
doc.LoadXml(encodedXml);
```

Error output:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

**How do I load this escaped XML into an XML Document object?**

Comment: Give it valid XML. Don't escape the angle brackets. They're significant. What you're doing is like giving this to a C# compiler: `var x = \"some text\";`. Only escape quote characters *within* the string. Don't escape the meaningful quote characters that *delimit* the string.

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't the class used for escaping be able to reverse it?

Comment: Your input XML is not valid because of the naked & and the malformed closing tag. Its unlikely you will be able to make it valid and thus treat it as XML unless you know what specific manual corrections to make.

Comment: There's nothing magic you can do here. The input isn't well formed XML. You can only 'fix' it with specific knowledge of the issues that might be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid XML document:

```
&lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
```

When you escape the angle brackets on the tags, they are no longer treated as tags by the XML parser. It's all just text in an element -- but there's no element containing it. In XML, there must be a root element. That's a requirement. It may be an arbitrary requirement, and that may be unjust, but you'll never win an argument with a parser.

What you're doing is like giving this to a C# compiler:

```
string s = \"foo\" bar\";
```

The outer quotes shouldn't be escaped.

**This is what you want:**

```
string xml = "<node>it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it</node>";
```

Note also that your original XML was *broken already*:

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
```

Your "closing" tag isn't a closing tag. It should be `</node>`, not `<node>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a response from another web application / API / service, it is likely that the contents are Html encoded.

Take a look at the `WebUtility` class, particularly, [HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) and [UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_). This is likely to convert your "string" data to proper Xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving valid XML back from the service you can convert the response using something like this:

```
//...
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse
((
    new System.IO.StreamReader
    (
        response.GetResponseStream()
    )
).ReadToEnd());
```

If you're receiving invalid XML from a service which should return valid XML, contact whoever owns/provides that service / raise a support ticket with them in the appropriate way.

Any other action is a hack.  Sometimes that may be required (e.g. when you're dealing with a legacy system that's no longer supported with bugs that have never been corrected), but pursue the non-hacky routes first.